# Split an array into two arrays whose values are greater than and less than given needle PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I do not want to use a loop (unless there is no other way). I know how to do this using foreach loop and building 2 arrays but I was wondering if built in function exists in PHP.

```
$arr = array(1 => 0.1, 2 => 0.20, 3 => 0.40, 4 => 0.60);
```

I want to get the resulting two arrays after the function call:

```
$twoArrays = split_arrays($arr, 0.3);
```

**$twoArrays** would hold the values:

```
array(
  0 => array(1 => 0.1, 2 => 0.20), 
  1 => array(3 => 0.40, 4 => 0.60)
);
```

Basically I want 1 array to hold all values **less than 0.3** and another **greater than 0.3**.

With loop I can do it, is there a PHP built in function?

**NOTE**: I need to keep the **keys** as it is.

Comment: Simple answer: `No there isn't`... in practical terms, two lines using array_filter with a callback is one alternative to a loop

Comment: Nope, a loop (or one of the '`callback`' array mapping/filtering/walking functions which boil down to the same thing, and a loop is more readable).

Comment: the php built in fumction would use a loop, internally. so ...

Comment: thanks guys, I know PHP built in function would use loop but I wanted simpled 1 line of code as opposed to few lines.

Comment: then dont add line breaks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `array_filter()` twice:

```
$bottom = array_filter($myArray, function($val){return ($val<=0.3)});

$top = array_filter($myArray, function($val){return ($val>0.3)});
```

Comment: A better solution might be to use `array_filter()` for the first case, and then `array_diff()` to get what's left - it prevents potential errors from writing essentially the same test twice.

Comment: Although that will not preserve keys, so it may not work in this specific instance.